# Using MSBuild with Hudson?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, hudson

I am building a CI Server using Hudson to deploy .NET applications.  My problem is that it keeps throwing the error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project 
"C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications
\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path
 in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Do I need to have VisualStudio installed on my CI server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annoyingly this Microsoft.WebApplication.targets file is only shipped with Visual Studio and not with the plain .NET SDK.

In principle it should be possible to take a working Visual Studio install and copy this file,  However, it doesn't appear to be as straightforward as copying one file. As you copy more and more stuff, you wonder where you cross the line from 'patching your SDK installation' to 're-creating the Visual Studio install' (and therefore requiring another licence).

In summary, installing Visual Studio appears to be the only way to build projects that need Microsoft.WebApplication.targets. Non-web projects work OK.

Comment: @Abe see how you get along. I don't have an example of what broke any more, so I can't be any more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the latest Windows SDK, as well as the VS2010 Integrated Shell.

Links :

[Windows SDK .Net 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279)

[VS2010 Integrated Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=115)

Answer (score 0):

Just Install VS2010 in the hudson host machine.